# How to show multiple screens with right/left slide Gesture

Tags: android, gesture

I am having an application in which i have a ListView .List is populated from an array list .
On selection of each item it show the detail description for that item in a seperate screen populated data from another array list .
A single screen is used to display details of all the items.it loads data from  dynamically.

Can anyone please tell me how can i display all details on same screen using right/left slide gesture.

Screen with ListView -itemList
Screen to display detail -detail listView
 on next and previous gesture it should dynamic data on screen 2detail list view from arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gallery View or horizon